# Service deployed in Kubernetes is working only via Proxy??? Not able to consume exposed endpoint

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have deployed java API in ACR and pushed to Kubernetes. I am able to post the data to the service when I use a proxy. but the same service is not working using exposed endpoint. PFB corresponding Kubernetes YAML file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: taxservice-deployment
  labels:
    app: taxserviceapi
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: taxserviceapi
      labels:
        app: taxserviceapi
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: taxserviceapi
        image : 3poacr.azurecr.io/3potaxservice:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      restartPolicy: Always
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcret5
  selector:
   matchLabels:
    app: taxserviceapi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: taxservice-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: taxserviceapi
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
```

Comment: You can't talk to through the NodePort?

Comment: Did you try "kubectl get service" to obtain the nodeport and use the node:nodeport to access the service. NodePort is usually 3xxxx.

Answer (score 3):

In your service definition, you need to replace spec.type from `NodePort` to e.g., `LoadBalancer`.

See more information here:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types

Answer (score 0):

Change your service type to LoadBalancer.
You can then check the exposed port by describing the service:

```
kubectl describe svc taxservice-service
```